# How to mock interface that accept Type argument and return another inteface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have this interface:

```
public interface IViewModelCache
{
    IViewModel GetViewModel(Type viewModelType);
}
```

And I'm mocking it with this code:

```
var cacheMock = Mock.Of<IViewModelCache>();

Mock.Get(cacheMock)
    .Setup(cache => cacheMock.GetViewModel(typeof(IViewModel)))
    .Returns(Mock.Of<IViewModel>());
```

But it throws

> "Specified method is not supported.",

what is wrong?

The stack trace is:

> at Moq.Mock.FluentMockVisitor.VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
>   at Moq.Mock.FluentMockVisitor.Accept()    at
>   Moq.Mock.FluentMockVisitor.Accept(Expression expression, Mock mock)
>   at Moq.Mock.GetInterceptor(Expression fluentExpression, Mock mock)
>   at Moq.Mock.<>c__DisplayClass65_0`2.<Setup>b__0()    at
>   Moq.PexProtector.Invoke[T](Func`1 function)    at
>   Moq.Mock.Setup[T,TResult](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression,
>   Condition condition)    at Moq.Mock`1.Setup[TResult](Expression`1
>   expression)

I have also tried that:

```
Mock.Get(cacheMock)
   .Setup(cache => cacheMock.GetViewModel(It.IsAny<Type>()))
   .Returns(Mock.Of<IViewModel>());
```

And that one:

```
Mock.Get(cacheMock)
   .Setup(cache => cacheMock.GetViewModel(It.IsAny<Type>()))
   .Returns(new Mock<IViewModel>().Object);
```

Both throws the same exception.

Comment: Can you post the call stack of the exception?

Comment: @PatrickQuirk, I posted it in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression in the Setup is wrong. Try making the code cleaner so that the intent is understood.

```
var cache = Mock.Of<IViewModelCache>();
var viewModel = Mock.Of<IViewModel>();
var viewModelType = typeof(IViewModel);

Mock.Get(cache)
   .Setup(mock => mock.GetViewModel(viewModelType))
   .Returns(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return the mock's object instead of the mock itself.

```
Returns(Mock.Of<IViewModel>())
```

should be

```
Returns(new Mock<IViewModel>().Object)
```

**Update**

Try this

```
var cacheMock = new Mock<IViewModelCache>();
cacheMock.Setup(c => c.GetViewModel(typeof(IViewModel)))
         .Returns(new Mock<IViewModel>().Object);
```

Comment: Mock.Get(cacheMock).Setup(cache => cacheMock.GetViewModel(It.IsAny<Type>())).Returns(new Mock<IViewModel>().Object); Also throws the same exception

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo:

```
Mock.Get(cacheMock)
    .Setup(cache => cacheMock.GetViewModel(typeof(IViewModel)))
    .Returns(Mock.Of<IViewModel>());
```

should be (note the `Setup` call):

```
Mock.Get(cacheMock)
    .Setup(cache => cache.GetViewModel(typeof(IViewModel)))
    .Returns(Mock.Of<IViewModel>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally that worked:

```
 public static IViewModelCache MockViewModelCache()
 {
     var cache = Mock.Of<IViewModelCache>();
     var viewModel = Mock.Of<RoutableViewModelBase<IReportData>>();

     Mock.Get(cache)
        .Setup(mock => mock.GetViewModel(It.IsAny<Type>)))
        .Returns(viewModel);

     return cache;
 }
```